# Find duplicate name in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm having a problem in getting the duplicate name in my mongodb to delete duplicates.

```
{
    "users": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "61441890a6566a001623b8ed"
        },
        "name": "Jollibee",
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "61441890a6566a001623b8ed"
        },
        "name": "Jollibee",
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "61441890a6566a001623b8ed"
        },
        "name": "MCDO",
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "61441890a6566a001623b8ed"
        },
        "name": "Burger King",
      },
    ]
  }
```

I want to show in my output only the duplicate names. which is `Jollibee`.

tried this approach but it only returns me the count of all the users not the duplicated ones. I want to show 2 `Jollibee` only.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$users"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": {
        "$ne": null
      },
      "count": {
        "$gt": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the `$unwind` step gives you same `_id` for all documents grouping by `_id` is not correct. Instead try grouping by `users.name`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$users"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$users.name",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": {
        "$ne": null
      },
      "count": {
        "$gt": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PBcgiX4OQHe)

Comment: Hello can I ask. why is it that when I put this on mongodb chart it's not working? `FunctionError: (InvalidPipelineOperator) Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$group'`

Comment: hmm im not quite sure where the addFields came from

Comment: it came from mongodb charts when you want to manually add field for mongodb aggregation

Comment: @PinkyPromise im sorry i havent used mongodb charts so cannot comment on that. did your previous query run properly

Comment: yes, it works. thanks for the help. searching for some alternatives for mongodb chart.

Comment: @PinkyPromise in the meantime you can try asking another question with the error you are getting with mongodb-charts tag added. maybe someone who knows can help

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the documents are:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "6226dd742ef592186422ad1d"
        },
        "name": "Stack test"
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "6226dd7d2ef592186422ad1e"
        },
        "name": "Stack test"
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "6226dd912ef592186422ad1f"
        },
        "name": "Stack test 001"
    }
]
```

Aggreagtion Query:

```
db.users.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$name", 
                names: {$push: "$name"}
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Result:

```
{ 
    _id: 'Stack test', 
    names: [ 'Stack test', 'Stack test' ] 
},
{ 
    _id: 'Stack test 001', 
    names: [ 'Stack test 001' ] 
}
```

But a better way to do it will be

Aggregation Query:

```
db.users.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$name", 
                count: {$sum: 1}
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Result:

```
{ 
    _id: 'Stack test',
    count: 2 
},
{ 
    _id: 'Stack test 001', 
    count: 1 
}
```

Now, you can iterate through the count and use the name value in _id

Comment: thank you! can I ask a question? do you know how can I insert that aggregate in Mongodbcharts?

Comment: No, I haven't worked with MongoDB charts. But  I just checked it now. It is working for me. Can you share what is it that you are giving as input in the aggregation pipeline?